# Shopify collection page url change

Tags: shopify

I would like to change collection all page to simply collection. Is it possible?
eg https://example.com/collections/all
to
https://example.com/collections/

Comment: No, you can't do the same into Shopify

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. Shopify has a fixed URL structure for all the different pages including product pages and collections.